# How do I display documents retrieved from firestore using GeoFlutterFire

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I'm trying to get documents from Firestore where the location of a restaurant is within a certain radius of the user's location. I am using the `geoflutterfire` package https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire. How can I display the query results as a snapshot rather than as a stream on my page?

Comment: A snapshot is a stream!! Why do you ask that?

Comment: Rather than keep listening to changes in Firestore,  I want the documents are they are when first accessed.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to listen to the documents just once. Simply convert the `Stream` to a `Future` and await it. To convert, append `.first` to the stream and then `await` it. E.g `List<DocumentSnapshot>> future = await geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference).within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field).first`;